# curl: (26) couldn't open file

Tags: php, api, curl, box-api

I am getting this error, when I am trying to call a box api through curl.

```
curl: (26) couldn't open file
```

Can't find why! I am calling this api with a correct file name-

```
curl https://upload.view-api.box.com/1/documents \
-H "Authorization: Token YOUR_API_TOKEN" \
-H "Content-type: multipart/form-data" \
-F file=@A_correct_file_name
```

I have seen all the three already asked questions but 2 of them are unanswered and one is specific to facebook.

[cURL error 26 couldn't open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248755/curl-error-26-couldnt-open-file)

[Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "" thrown in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197530/fatal-error-uncaught-curlexception-26-couldnt-open-file-thrown-in)

[Getting Fatal Error Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568785/getting-fatal-error-uncaught-curlexception-26-couldnt-open-file)

Comment: Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: @Shubham I have done this **'chmod 777 .'** in the directory which contains the file. Isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry guys! My bad. I had not included extension of the file in the file name. After including it, it worked. I am answering this in case someone does the same mistake in future.

Comment: upvoted because this helped me discover that I had munged the filename.

Answer (score 27):

I was having a similar problem after changing to PHP 5 (I was using the `@` upload method and it was deprecated, so I had to start using `CURLFile`), and the solution to my problem was found in this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127732/change-name-of-upload-file-in-curl/15169730#15169730).

**Solution:** curl upload won't work with *relative paths*, use the full path instead

Answer (score 10):

For my case, using relative path didn't work. But changing it to a absolute path fixes it.

This failed

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
    -F "file=@~/Downloads/xxx.csv" http://localhost:6708/upload
```

This worked

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
    -F "file=@/Users/myself/Downloads/xxx.csv" http://localhost:6708/upload
```

Comment: Really weird, but Inside a Dockerfile works for me if I run docker locally but it doesn't work when it run in Azure DevOps. I fix it using absolute path instead of relative.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem this morning but I solved with this

```
fileUpload=@\"file, with comma .txt\"
```

So you have to put some double quotes around the file name if you have commas in the file name ( \" )

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with relative paths like @Guilherme did too. I was running my bash script with:

```
bash test/script.sh
```

However, my file was in the same directory level as the bash script and not the `test` directory (where I was calling bash from), so the script could not find my file.

**Solution for me:**
1. cd into /test and run bash script.sh from there
2. Use absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

I am using PlateRecognizer.com to secure license plate information from pics that I have isolated from videos from my dashcam. I was having so many problems with the exact code. PlateRecognizer did not provide the correct information in their help section.

I work using my Windows 10 laptop. This code is what finally worked for me:

```
curl -F upload=@/”Users/Me/Desktop/Driver1.mp4” -F regions=us-az -H “Authorization: Token 4892e779f97d879df6453” https://api.platerecognizer.com/v1/plate-reader/
```

Make note of the double quote marks around the file path and name - not single quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

Luis Cruz is correct: quotes are required around the filename, but I needed to use the 'file' keyword, not 'fileUpload', as is it shown in the question.

```
curl -X GET \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F file=@"/path/to/file.ext" \ 
'http://host:port/path/to/dir'
```