# curl_exec returns false when trying to upload image to Prestashop using PHP

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add photo for existing product in my Prestashop 1.7.5.1 shop. I found example code on: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/webservice/tutorials/change_product_image/ and changed it so it has my shop addres and my key. I also changed line

`$args['image'] = new CurlFile($image_path, $image_mime);` to

`$args['image'] = new CurlFile($image_path, $image_mime, '1.jpg');`
beacause Visual Studio Code highlighted that CurlFile also needs third argument - postname.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    define('DEBUG', true);
    $url = 'http://test.my_shop.com';
    $key  = 'MY_AUTH_KEY';

    $psProductId = '2364';
    $urlImage = $url.'/api/images/products/'.$psProductId.'/';

    $image_path = '/img/1.jpg';
    $image_mime = 'image/jpg';
    $args['image'] = new CurlFile($image_path, $image_mime, '1.jpg');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlImage);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);

    print("<pre>");
    echo '<br>curl_exec <br>';
    $data_exec = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($data_exec);
    echo '<br>curl_getinfo <br>';
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo '<br>curl_errno <br>';
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    echo '<br>curl_error <br>';
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    print("</pre>");

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I placed all those var_dumps because I wanted to gather as much info as possible. When I run this code in my browser using XAMPP i get following output:

```
curl_exec 
bool(false)

curl_getinfo 
array(37) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(48) "http://test.my_shop.com/api/images/products/2364/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.032204)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.001465)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.031879)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(15) "123.123.123.123"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(13) "192.168.0.106"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(13956)
  ["http_version"]=>
  int(0)
  ["protocol"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ssl_verifyresult"]=>
  int(0)
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "HTTP"
  ["appconnect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_time_us"]=>
  int(31879)
  ["namelookup_time_us"]=>
  int(1465)
  ["pretransfer_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["starttransfer_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time_us"]=>
  int(32204)
}

curl_errno 
string(0) ""

curl_error 
string(0) ""
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I don't know why code posted on documentation page is not working dor me. If someone has any suggestion please post them, thanks.

Comment: Does your logs show anything?

Comment: You're printing `curl_error()` when you should be printing `curl_errno()`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your comment. I changed my code and thanks to that I was able to correct my code. I post it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected first `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` in my code and replaced it with `var_dump(curl_errno($ch));`. After i ran the code I got error no. 26

```
curl_errno
int(26)
```

I looked it up and found this answer: [curl: (26) couldn't open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730283/curl-26-couldnt-open-file/28676891#28676891). I changed relative path to full path and now my code is fully working, photos are uploaded correctly. Here is my corrected code:

```
<?php
    define('DEBUG', true);
    $url = 'http://test.my_shop.com';
    $key  = 'MY_AUTH_KEY';

    $psProductId = '2364';
    $urlImage = $url.'/api/images/products/'.$psProductId.'/';

    $image_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/my_folder/img/1.jpg';
    $image_mime = 'image/jpg';
    $args['image'] = new CurlFile($image_path, $image_mime, '1.jpg');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlImage);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);

    print("<pre>");
    echo '<br>curl_exec <br>';
    $data_exec = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($data_exec);
    echo '<br>curl_getinfo <br>';
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo '<br>curl_errno <br>';
    var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
    echo '<br>curl_error <br>';
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    print("</pre>");

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: It's too bad that `curl_error()` doesn't show that. I guess it only shows errors that come from the server, not local errors.