# curl: (26) couldn't open file "/C:/Users/msaini/Music/xylemesandbox.zip"

Tags: curl

curl -F 'file=@/C:/Users/msaini/Music/xylemesandbox.zip' https://****/api/v3/upload/toDocument/12458

I'm executing above statement on my Windows machine and it's giving couldn't open file error. I have tried all the solutions mentioned at below URL but I'm not able to solve.

[curl: (26) couldn't open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730283/curl-26-couldnt-open-file)

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: You're in windows: you have to use double quotes, `"..."`, for argument quoting. You can't use single quotes. Having said that, did you confirm that file exists, with that exact lettercase?

Comment: I have tried with " "  and file path is correct as well but getting same error.

Comment: you forgot to answer the most important question: did you confirm the file exists, with that exact lettercase?